# Add CashU payment gateway to Wordpress Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway

I'm having trouble adding [CashU](https://www.cashu.com/) payment in **WooCommerce (version 2.3.6) Wordpress (version 4.1.1)**

I've already googled my query, but no luck. I found this [guide](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/payment-gateway-api/) but I don't know where to put it or where should I start.

I tried hardcoding the payment option but the backend does not allow me to continue because the option does not exist. I'm stuck in **add_action and do_action functions**, I think if I can find that function I can add an exception for my CashU payment.

My expertise is on cakephp and other php framework. I don't have any experience in using Wordpress or any other platform similar to it, but my boss insisted I should do this work and add the cashu payment.. I don't have other choices but to follow.

**Any idea would be much appreciated or any other payment that might be similar to this. Thanks in advance**

Comment: You can either hire someone who does know WooCommerce or you can purchase one of their other payment gateways and reverse engineer that. On the WooCommerce side they are all very similar and differ mostly in the third party api.

Answer (score 2):

I just finished making a Woocommerce Payment gateway too.. it took me about 15 hours from scratch.

I started with this guide.
http://www.sitepoint.com/building-a-woocommerce-payment-extension/

and this guide:
http://www.mrova.com/lets-create-a-payment-gateway-plugin-payu-for-woocommerce/

I actually learnt the most from looking through the code from these two professional ones:

https://github.com/Paymium/WooCommerce/blob/master/checkout.php

https://github.com/tubiz/voguepay-woocommerce-payment-gateway/blob/master/voguepay-woocommerce-payment-gateway.php

my entire code for the whole thing ended up being just one file. and just press "activate" in the plugins window of wordpress for your gateway.

```
/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-payment-gateway-kiwipay/woocommerce-payment-gateway-kiwipay.php
```

Comment: can I get that kiwipay plugin that you created?

Answer (score 1):

Try this sdk for cashu https://github.com/AlaaKanaan/payment-getaway-soap-sdk

**The SDK include this features:**

- Standard
- Premier
- Basic security token
- Enhanced security token
- Standard StandingOrder
- Refund
- Merchant Services

**install:**
composer require alaakanaan/cashu-soap-php-sdk:dev-master

```
    use Cashu\CashuClient;
    $client = new CashuClient();

    $payment = new \Cashu\lib\model\Payment();

    $payment->setAmount(200);
    $payment->setCurrency('USD');
    $payment->setDisplayText('test payment');
    $payment->setLanguage('en');
    $payment->setSessionId('11');
    $payment->setTxt1('test text 1');

    $html=$client->getPremierMethod($payment->getTransactionCode());
    return $html;
```